# C++ creating object with *new

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I have a method with my custom object as a parameter:

```
void processObject(Myobject instance)
{
 //some code using instance
}
```

I'm calling method above from another method like this:

```
...

processObject(*new MyObject());

...
```

Could this cause a memory leak? Should I call something like delete &instance in my process object method?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**EDIT**

ok now I know that there is memory leak, what would you suggest as the easiest way to fix this? My idea is to change this code:

```
void processObject(Myobject* instance)
{
 //some code using instance
    delete instance;
}

...

processObject(new MyObject());

...
```

I need as easy and fast way to fix this as possible (same issue in the code on many many places).

Comment: Why do you use `new` in the first place? Why not just `processObject(MyObject());` ?

Comment: Did you call `delete` anywhere? No, because you can't. So you have a memory leak.

Comment: no delete was never called - I got into this project and found this code on many places. So the easiest way to fix this could be:

Answer (score 2):

You can not delete the instance object that the `processObject` procedure receives, because it is a copy of the object you created with `new`. Imagine it like that:

1. You create a new object using `new`, this creates the object on the heap and gives you a `MyObject*`
2. You dereference the pointer, therefore you have an object of type `MyObject`. Here you also lose the pointer, as you don't store it anywhere
3. You pass the object to the `processObject` method, and as the signature of that function states, a copy of your object is created and passed to the function

As you have lost the pointer, you can not delete it anymore.

A solution would be not allocating the object with `new` and passing a refrence to the process method:

```
void processObject(MyObject& ref) {
    // do something with the reference
}

void test() {
    MyObject x;
    processObject(x);
    // do stuff with x
}
```

Or allocating it with `new` and doing this:

```
void processObject(MyObject* ptr) {
    // do something with the pointer
}

void test() {
    MyObject* x = new MyObject();
    processObject(x);
    // do stuff with x
    delete x;
}
```

Comment: And not forgetting to delete it afterwards, and considering using RAII or smart pointer

Comment: Right, added the `delete` ;)

Comment: Sure not, but thats not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should delete after a new, but you can not delete this newly created object.

Whenever you write `*new x;`, you are dereferencing a pointer into an actual reference (or object).
In your case, Myobject is passed by value and is thus copied, leaving your pointer not within stack space and thus causing a memory leak.

I suggest you use the following calling procedure with nearly the same effect: (without the memory leak):
`processObject(MyObject());`

I think you may have gotten the new syntax from Java, where we are forced to use it. In C++, you can simply call the constructor implicitly like this and have a new object be constructed in-place, which is then passed as function argument.
In this case the object is constructed on the stack and thereby has automatic storage duration (no memory leak).

Answer (score 0):

As it stands it will memory leak. You could delete the object inside the `processObject` function by taking the address, however the signature

```
void processObject(Myobject instance)
```

doesn't prevent someone from passing a local variable/stack object.

```
Myobject instance;
processObject(instance);
```

If this happens you can't `delete` the object.

Avoid using raw pointers, and avoid confusing users of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject() { std::cout << "Reporting construction of object (ptr: " << (int)this << ")\n"; }
    MyObject(const MyObject & other) { std::cout << "Reporting copy-construction of object (ptr: " << (int)this << ")\n"; }
    MyObject(MyObject && other) { std::cout << "Reporting move-construction of object (ptr: " << (int)this << ")\n"; }
    virtual ~MyObject() { std::cout << "Reporting destruction of object (ptr: " << (int)this << ")\n"; }
};

void DoSomething(MyObject obj)
{
}

int main()
{
    DoSomething(*new MyObject());
}
```

Result:

```
Reporting construction of object (ptr: 140173320)
Reporting copy-construction of object (ptr: -1078250292)
Reporting destruction of object (ptr: -1078250292)
```

As you see, first instance was not destroyed - thus leaked.