# Why is there no memory leak here

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I was trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799036/c-creating-object-with-new) question, so I decided to create the following simple test case so that the OP could see by himself the memory leak.

```
#include<iostream>

class MyObject
{
public:
   MyObject(){std::cout << "creation of my object" << std::endl;}
   virtual ~MyObject(){std::cout << "destruction of my object" << std::endl;}
};

void processMyObject(MyObject foo)
{
}

int main()
{
   processMyObject(*new MyObject());
   return 0;
}
```

I compiled it :

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

And then, I saw an unexpected output :

```
creation of my object
destruction of my object
```

I have absolutly no idea of what is happening here. Could anyone explain to me ?

PS: I used g++ 4.6.3

Comment: There is a memory leak. You need to instrument the copy and move copy constructors too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you pass an object by value to the function, you incurr a copy or move-copy construction. But you are not keeping track of that with your primitive memory leak checker. You could provide your own copy constructor, and then you will see two objects are being created, and only one is being destroyed:

```
#include<iostream>

class MyObject
{
public:
  MyObject() {std::cout << "creation of my object" << std::endl;}
  MyObject(const MyObject&) {std::cout << "copy creation of my object" << std::endl;}
  ~MyObject() {std::cout << "destruction of my object" << std::endl;}
};

void processMyObject(MyObject foo) {}

int main() 
{
  processMyObject(*new MyObject());
}
```

Output:

```
creation of my object
copy creation of my object
destruction of my object
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you're taking the `MyObject` by value.

Thus there is a destruction. But it is the destruction of the `foo` argument at the end of `processMyObject`.

The `*new` does actually still leak in this case.

**EDIT**: As pointed out by juanchopanza, you need to also print a statement in the copy constructor and in the move constructor as well.

Comment: @doctorlove Actually, it was pointed out in the comment. I edited to mention it :)

Comment: Oh, now I get it. And I'm kind of ashamed I couldn't find it by myself. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

**What happens in your code**

- You construct an object and get information about it (`creation of my object`)
- You pass it to function - copy constructor fires, but does not report anything
- The copy is destroyed - you get information about it (`destruction of my object`)
- The original instance leaks despite fact, that you don't have any information about it.

**How to see it?**

Simply report pointers to `this` during construction and destruction (quick'n'dirty, please don't complain):

```
class MyObject
{
public:
   MyObject(){std::cout << "creation of my object (" << (int)this << ")" << std::endl;}
   virtual ~MyObject(){std::cout << "destruction of my object (" << (int)this << ")" << std::endl;}
};
```

Result:

```
creation of my object (165437448)
destruction of my object (-1076708692)
```

As you see, destroyed object is different than created one.

**How to "fix" it to show the leak?**

The simplest way to "fix" your code is to pass object by pointer:

```
#include<iostream>

class MyObject
{
public:
   MyObject(){std::cout << "creation of my object" << std::endl;}
   virtual ~MyObject(){std::cout << "destruction of my object" << std::endl;}
};

void processMyObject(MyObject * foo)
{
}

int main()
{
   processMyObject(new MyObject());
   return 0;
}
```

Another option is to report copy ctors and move ctors as well:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
   MyObject(){std::cout << "creation of my object" << std::endl;}
   MyObject(const MyObject & obj) { std::cout << "copy-ctor" << std::endl; }
   MyObject(MyObject && obj) { std::cout << "move-ctor" << std::endl; }
   virtual ~MyObject(){std::cout << "destruction of my object" << std::endl;}
};
```

Comment: @doctorlove I posted an answer there as well. Printing pointer to this along with construction/destruction report is a simple and powerful way to track memory leaks :)

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a memory leak. Just because your object was destroyed, doesn't mean that you deleted the resources you acquired with `new`. You have to explicitly use `delete`.

**EDIT**

So here's what's happening:

1. You are calling the default constructor on the fly, and passing it to the function call. This prints the first message.
2. As part of the function call, the object is passing to `processMyObject()`, creating a new object in that scope using the *copy constructor*, which has been implicitly defined by the compiler.
3. When that object (in `processMyObject()`) goes out of scope, its destructor is called, printing the second message.

So, the instance printing the first message is different from that printing the second one.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: True but the question is why can we see something being deleted?